# nuxt3 and deploay problem with server folder

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt3

I have application with nuxt3 that calls an API from other server in server folder, then calls an API from vue file and use data. When deploy application with `npm run generate`, network tab give me 404 for this route. Does anyone have any idea?

simple `server/api/file`:

```
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const { public: base } = useRuntimeConfig(event);
  const cookies = parseCookies(event);
  const headers = {
    "Accept-Language": cookies.ln,
  };
  const { data } = await $fetch(`mybaseurl/home`, {
    headers: headers,
  });
  return data;
});
```

Then I call this file from `vue.file` like this:

```
const { data, pending } = await useFetch("/api/home");
storeHome.setHomeData(data.value);
```

Comment: I have an idea:  Post your code so someone has any chance of helping you.

Comment: What URL are you visiting to view this response?  A 404 indicates a "Not Found" error so unless we can see the URL used to access, then we can't be certain you aren't just using the wrong link!!  If the structure is in fact `~/server/api/file` then you should be able to access that at `http://localhost:3000/api/file` by default HOWEVER, with you running the `npm run generate` command then you need a server to serve said files over localhost.  You should probably also specify the correct URL you are using in the fetch request too, rather than `mybaseurl`.

Comment: every thing on localhost is ok,api folder is in server folder and i call api from this folder with $fetch like :   const { data , pending } = await useFetch("/api/products");

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the server endpoints on a generated site as there is no server running!!

If you wish to make use of server-side functionality, then you need to be running a build rather than a generated site.  Please use the `npm run build` command followed by `npm run preview`.

You should then be able to access `http://localhost:3000/api/file` in your browser.

Comment: in localhost every things is ok
but when i deploy project with npm run generate and use dist folder to upload in public_html some of api routes not found and in network tab give me 404 error